# Plot Width Error with pgfplot's groupplot in Beamer

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, groupplots

I am making a 3x3 matrix of plots in a beamer slide. Position (1,1) is empty, the rest of the first row has column titles and the rest of the first column has row titles. Positions (2,2) to (3,3) contain actual plots. I am using `groupplots` (`pgfplots` 1.12) to make such a matrix.

I receive the following two error messages:

> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in
>   direction y). R eplacing it with a default range and clearing all
>   plots. on input line 139.
>
> ! Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot width `28.45274pt' is too small.
>   This can not be implemented while maintaining constant size for
>   labels. Sorry, label siz es are only approximate. You will need to
>   adjust your width..

In the case of the second error, I don't really know where to increase the width. Can you please help me to fix my code so I don't get the errors mentioned above?

The intended outcome is the following image.

[image: Intended Outcome]

My code so far is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Distribution Matrix}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=my plots,
            group size=3 by 3,
        },
        footnotesize,
        tickpos=left,
        ytick align=outside,
        xtick align=outside,
        enlarge x limits=false 
    ]

\nextgroupplot[
            width=1cm,
            height=1cm,
            hide axis]

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=1cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis line style = { draw = none },
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            xlabel={Column 1},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=1cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis line style = { draw = none },
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            xlabel={Column 2},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]

\nextgroupplot[
            width=1cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style = { draw = none },
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ylabel={Row 1},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=1cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style = { draw = none },
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ylabel={Row 2},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]    

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(2.5,0) (2.5,0.4)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [dashed,very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(2.5,0) (2.5,0.4)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not use empty `\nextgroupplot` to insert the `Row 1` etc. But use a node like

```
\node[rotate=90,above=5mm] at (my plots c1r1.west) {Row 1};
\node[rotate=90,above=5mm] at (my plots c1r2.west) {Row 2};
\node[above=5mm] at (my plots c1r1.north) {Column 1};
\node[above=5mm] at (my plots c2r1.north) {Column 2};
```

The width problem comes as you have `width=1cm` etc in those empty `\nextgroupplot`s which is very small and `pgfplots` complains about it.

Here is your refined code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Distribution Matrix}
%\centering if you want to center this
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=my plots,
            group size=2 by 2,
        },
        footnotesize,
        tickpos=left,
        ytick align=outside,
        xtick align=outside,
        enlarge x limits=false
    ]


\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(2.5,0) (2.5,0.4)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\nextgroupplot[
            width=5cm,
            height=4cm,
            no markers, domain=0:9, samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={->},
            xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.01)},anchor=north},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.01,0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            ticks=none,
            axis on top]
    \addplot [dashed,very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};
    \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(2.5,0) (2.5,0.4)};
    \addplot [thick,red, no markers] coordinates {(5.5,0.0) (5.5,0.4)};

\end{groupplot}
\node[rotate=90,above=5mm] at (my plots c1r1.west) {Row 1};
\node[rotate=90,above=5mm] at (my plots c1r2.west) {Row 2};
\node[above=5mm] at (my plots c1r1.north) {Column 1};
\node[above=5mm] at (my plots c2r1.north) {Column 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]